# Relative $0$-homology of $(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

Let $\Delta^n$ be the standard $n$-simplex, with $n>0$. Denote with $H_0$ the (simplicial) $0$-homology.

In my book it is written that $H_0(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)=\mathbb{Z}$. But $\Delta^n$ and $\partial \Delta^n$ have the same number of vertices, so $H_0(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)=0$. Is it just a typo of the book? Am I wrong?

Comment: It's most likely a typo. Note that $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial\Delta^n)=\Bbb Z$ for every $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, and this is presumably a typo.  I would guess that the error arose from the fact that for non-relative homology, $H_0$ being "trivial" means it is $\mathbb{Z}$, rather than $0$.